# Why this program does not recognize the void function?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been trying to create this console application on C#.NET but I get this error message:

> Error 1   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

I'm new to C#, I did C++ before.

**MAIN FILE:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


public void Main(string[] args)
{
  string repositories = args[0];
  string transaction = args[1];

  var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                           {
                             FileName = "svnlook.exe",
                             UseShellExecute = false,
                             CreateNoWindow = true,
                             RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                             RedirectStandardError = true,
                             Arguments = String.Format("log -t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", transaction, repositories)
                           };

  var p = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
  var s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  p.WaitForExit();

  if (s == string.Empty)
  {
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Message must be provided");
    Environment.Exit(1);
  }

  Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You don't have a class.  This is also true in C++.  This easily could have been researched.

Comment: What do you mean by "easily" , I did not know that C# required a class. I looked at some C# tutorials but passing from tutorials to actual programing, you forget few things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every method in C# must be contained within a `class` or `struct`. There's no way to define free-standing ("top level") functions in C#.

Try:

```
public class Program
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
```

And an extra `}` at the end.

If you're coming from a C++ background, as you indicate, you also shouldn't assume that `struct` and `class` have the same similarities and differences as in C++.

Answer (score 8):

Main needs to be static.

```
public static void Main
```

Also you need to wrap it into a namespace which has a class inside it. A standard console app template provided by VS 2010 looks like this, so you can have a look at it:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: This won't fix the reported compiler error.

Comment: thats not the main problem, as you can see its declared as a root member wich is not possible for a method in c#. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Yup your right, have edited to show that. He doesn't have a namespace or class. So that's the first problem.

Comment: @Arran namespace is not required.

Comment: Of course it isn't, however he's new at C#. If he's using VS (which I am assuming though) it's what you are given anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a class in your program =). Asweel as namespace. Then the Main void should be a static method

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: namespace is not always necesary, it will compile even without the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

First of all did you include the method in a class or struct?

You must declare a method contained in a class or struct, because a method is not a root member.

Answer (score 1):

Main needs to be static, and inside a class:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 

public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        string repositories //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions in C# must be inside of a class or struct. Only delegates, classes, structs, enums, and interfaces can exist at the namespace level.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] paArguments) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: +1 for an answer that reflects the compiler error message ("Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct").